# how to use xsl to retrieve all the district because the xml structure have some problem but i dont want to change?

Tags: xml, xslt

How do I select all districts from the xml file? When I read the district it returns the first row only?

Expected output:

[image]

XML Input:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE states SYSTEM "states.dtd">
<states>  
    <state sID="1">
        <statename>Perak</statename>    
        <disctrict>Setiawan</disctrict>
        <disctrict>Ipoh</disctrict>
        <disctrict>Kampar</disctrict>   
    </state>
    <state sID="2">
        <statename>Selangor</statename> 
        <disctrict>Petaling</disctrict>
        <disctrict>Setapak</disctrict>
        <disctrict>Cheras</disctrict>
        <disctrict>Rawang</disctrict>
    </state>
    <state sID="3">
        <statename>Penang</statename>    
        <disctrict>Balik Pulau</disctrict>
        <disctrict>Bayan Lepas</disctrict>     
    </state>
</states>
```

Below is the xsl file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            
            <body>
                <h2>Kawan Food Company Delivery States</h2>
                <table border="10" width="20%" bgcolor="blue">
                    <tr bgcolor="yellow" >
                        <th>---States---</th>
                        
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="states/state">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="disctrict"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
                
            </body>
            
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: When using xsl:value-of in XSLT, you’ll only get the string value of the first node selected. How to handle that depends on what you want the output to look like. Also, please don’t use pictures of your code; add the code itself. It makes it hard for others to reproduce your issue. (Hopefully someone can link to the description of a “minimal, reproducible example”.)

Comment: hi therefore that is no other solution?

Comment: The solution depends on what you need/want the output to be. Do you want all the districts in a single td separated by commas? Do you want a separate td for each district?

Comment: yes i want a separate td for each district but dont know how to do it can you help me?

Comment: i want a <tr> that contain the statename and separate <td> of each district

Comment: @HengPhin Please edit your question and add 1. an example XML input (as code, not as picture) 2. your current and complete XSLT (as code, not as picture) 3. the expected output (as HTML code) - see: [mcve].

Comment: ya sorry first time to use stackflow to asking question yes i already make some changes hope have the asnwers

Comment: You still haven't showed us the expected output. Since each state has a different number of districts, your request to have "a separate td for each district" would produce an irregularly shaped table - is that what you really want?

Comment: the expected output i have update at the hyperlink that you can click it sorry not familiar with this

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkM9g.png  here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want a separate td for each district

The result you show (and which you should have posted **as code** instead of as link to a picture) does NOT have a separate `td` for each district. It puts all the districts in the same `td`, separated only by a line break.

To get such result, you could do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/states">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>Kawan Food Company Delivery States</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <!-- head -->
                <tr>
                    <th>State</th>
                    <th>Districts</th>
                </tr>
                <!-- body -->
                <xsl:for-each select="state">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="statename"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:for-each select="disctrict">   
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                <br/>
                            </xsl:for-each> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>     
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Alternatively, you could create a separate `tr` for each district:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/states">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>Kawan Food Company Delivery States</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <!-- head -->
                <tr>
                    <th>State</th>
                    <th>Districts</th>
                </tr>
                <!-- body -->
                <xsl:for-each select="state">
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="{count(disctrict)}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="statename"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="disctrict[1]"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="disctrict[position() > 1]">   
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each> 
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result here will look something like:

[image]

Add your own CSS to taste.

Comment: thanks guys finally get mine expected output

Comment: hi michael may i know how to accepting the answer? where to accept